# hibernate search query from a list that match exactly from the child table with one-many relation ship

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using `spring-boot` and `hibernate`. I am using `one to many relationships`.

In the main table, it has the details of the user logs like

`jobId(pk), department, startDate. The child table is the category table(Id(pk),catId,catDesc,jobId(fk))`

i.e each `jobId` in the parent table can have multiple categories. Now I want to get all the values from the main table and child table that exactly matches with the List of categories(child table values).

```
createQuery("select * from parent p, child c where p.jobId=c.jobId AND c.catId IN ("+catId+" ) )
```

here `catId` is a list of values. But I want to get only those values that match all the values and the query is dynamic.

```
package com.assorted.product.model;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;`enter code here`
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "JOB_ID")
    private long jobId;
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private String userId;
    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_NAME")
    private String countryName;
    @Column(name = "DEPT_ID")
    private long depId;
    @Column(name = "DEPT_NAME")
    private String depName;
    @Column(name = "START_DATE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date startDate;
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="JOB_ID",referencedColumnName="JOB_ID")
    private Set<CategoryLogs> categoryLogs;
    public long getJobId() {
        return jobId;
    }
    public void setJobId(long jobId) {
        this.jobId = jobId;
    }
    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }
    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }
    public long getDepId() {
        return depId;
    }
    public void setDepId(long depId) {
        this.depId = depId;
    }
    public String getDepName() {
        return depName;
    }
    public void setDepName(String depName) {
        this.depName = depName;
    }
    public Date getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }
    public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }
    public Set<CategoryLogs> getCategoryLogs() {
        return categoryLogs;
    }
    public void setCategoryLogs(Set<CategoryLogs> categoryLogs) {
        this.categoryLogs = categoryLogs;
    }
}

package com.assorted.product.model;
import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
public class CategoryLogs {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "CAT_ID")
    private long catId;
    @Column(name = "CAT_NAME")
    private String catName;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "JOB_ID")
    private Parent parent;
    public CategoryLogs(){
    }
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public long getCatId() {
        return catId;
    }
    public void setCatId(long catId) {
        this.catId = catId;
    }
    public String getCatName() {
        return catName;
    }
    public void setCatName(String catName) {
        this.catName = catName;
    }
    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }
    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please show pojos.

Comment: @AngadBansode  I have added the pojos , Could you please look in to it.

Comment: so you want fetch all records from both table based on ID(pk) and cat_id (from CategoryLogs). For this you should use join fetch where. See my answer.

Comment: @USaikiran I have the same requirement now. Can you please post the solution, if you already solved it?

Answer (score 0):

**JOIN FETCH**.

The FETCH keyword of the JOIN FETCH statement is JPA-specific. It tells the persistence provider to not only join the 2 database tables within the query but to also initialize the association on the returned entity. You can use it with a JOIN and a LEFT JOIN statement.

```
List<Parent> parents = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Parent p JOIN FETCH p.categoryLogs c 
  WHERE c.catId IN (:cat_Ids) " , Parent.class)
  .setParameterList("cat_Ids",your_cat_id_list )
   .getResultList();
```

Comment: it is returning even if one value in the list matches the records, my use case is to return only if all the values in the list match.